# Сочи Парк, Сочи-парк, Сочи парк?

Tags: выбор-слов, выбор

Парк развлечений, расположенный в городе Сочи... Сочи Парк, Сочи-парк, Сочи парк? Что в таком случае выбрать?

Answer (score 2):

Он называется Сочи Парк.

> Сочи Парк — тематический парк развлечений в городе Сочи. Расположен в
> Адлерском районе, на территории Имеретинской низменности [[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA)].

Если использовать как название, то Сочи Парк.

«Парк развлечений, расположенный в городе Сочи» — тоже правильно, но тут может иметься ввиду как этот парк, как и любой другой парк развлечений, расположенный в городе Сочи.

«Сочи-парк» — если рассматривать как географическое наименование тоже можно, а если слова переставить местами, то «парк Сочи». «Сочи парк» без дефиса неправильно, поскольку приложение «Сочи» стоит впереди родового наименования «парк».

> Дефис пишется после имени собственного (чаще всего — географического названия, выступающего в роли приложения при родовом
> наименовании): Москва-река, Ильмень-озеро, Казбек-гора,
> Астрахань-город (но при обратном порядке слов: река Москва, озеро
> Ильмень, гора Казбек, город Астрахань; выражения типа матушка-Русь,
> матушка-земля имеют характер устойчивых сочетаний).
>
> После собственного имени лица дефис ставится только в случае слияния
> определяемого существительного и приложения в одно сложное
> интонационно-смысловое целое: Иван-царевич, Иванушка-дурачок,
> Аника-воин, Дюма-отец, Рокфеллер-старший (но: Катон Старший — прозвище
> исторического лица, Марк Порций Катон Младший, или Утический — перевод
> прозвища с латинского языка) [[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)].

Однако обращаю ваше внимание, что «Сочи-парк» и «парк Сочи» было бы, если бы он назывался «Сочи», а он называется «Сочи Парк».

---

**Возникает вопрос, почему в Сочи Парк оба слова с большой буквы.**

На мой взгляд, имеет место подражание английскому языку, в котором принято писать каждое знаменательное слово в названии с прописной буквы:

> **8. Первая буква каждого главного слова в названии**
>
> Снова, истинно английский подход писать слова в названии с больших   букв, в то время
> как в русском в основном заглавная только первая буква в названии:
>
> *How to Write Essays in English*
>
> *Gone with the Wind*
>
> *Heart of Darkness As*
> ...
> [[stapravda.ru](https://stapravda.ru/20141020/10_pravil_ispolzovaniya_zaglavnoy_bukvy_v_angliyskom_yazyke_80185.html)]

Примеры названий развлекательных парков со словом «парк» в названии на английском:

- [Disneyland Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disneyland)
- [Magic Kingdom Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Kingdom)
- [Thorpe Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorpe_Park)

---

Есть ещё одна версия:

> Нарицательные существительные в составных географических названиях
> пишутся с прописной буквы, если они употреблены не в своем обычном
> значении, напр.: Новая Земля, Огненная Земля (архипелаги), Золотой Рог
> (бухта), Чешский Лес (горы), Белая Церковь, Минеральные Воды, Сосновый
> Бор, Вятские Поляны, Царское Село (города), Пушкинские Горы, Камское
> Устье (поселки), Голодная Губа (озеро), Большой Бассейн (плоскогорье),
> Золотые Ворота (пролив), Кузнецкий Мост, Охотный Ряд, Земляной Вал
> (улицы), Никитские Ворота, Рогожская Застава (площади), Марьина Роща
> (район в Москве), Елисейские Поля (улица в Париже). [[ПРАВИЛА РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ ПОЛНЫЙ АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИЙ СПРАВОЧНИК](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=84#pp84)]

Это Сочи Парк вроде бы не географическое название, но с другой стороны слово «Парк» тут употреблено не в своем обычном значении. Тут парк – это не просто место усаженное деревьями, а развлекательный центр.

Однако если посмотреть на их сайт, то в названия двух аттракционов у них тоже пишутся все слова с прописных букв: Квантовый Скачок, Колесо Времени. Так что я думаю, что всё-таки тут дело в английском языке. Возможно, создатели парка вдохновлялись каким-то иностранным парком и скопировали инстранное правописание.

---

**Так же возникает вопрос, почему в название организации выглядит АО «Сочи-Парк», а не АО «Сочи Парк».**

Я думаю, причины тут в юридической плоскости, а в частности в сложности использования названия города в названии организации.

В публикации «[Как не допустить ошибок в названии ООО](https://pravodocs.ru/article/kak-ne-dopustit-oshibok-v-nazvanii-ooo)» на сайте [pravodocs.ru](https://pravodocs.ru/)  говорится о сложности использования названия города в ООО, но я думаю от АО особых отличий данном случае нет.

> **Можно ли использовать в названии ООО название города?**
>
> Хороший вопрос. Прямого запрета в ГК РФ нет. НО есть судебная
> практика: суды признают правомерным отказы налоговой службы в
> регистрации юридических лиц, **если в их наименованиях содержатся
> наименования городов** или субъектов РФ.   Приведу пример. Дело №
> А40-87094.   МИ ФНС № 46 города Москвы  отказала в регистрации
> Общества с ограниченной ответственностью «Московское бюро судебной
> защиты», по причине несоответствия наименования требованиям
> федерального закона.  Заявитель не согласился с таким решением и
> обратился в суд. Однако суд поддержал решение МИ ФНС №46 города Москвы
> и отказал в удовлетворении иска своим решением.   В аргументации суд
> сослался на статью 1473 ГК РФ и пояснил, что использование слов
> «Московское бюро судебной защиты» **может вызвать у потребителей
> стойкую ассоциацию с участием государства в деятельности такой
> организации, либо с особой значимостью деятельности данной организации
> в государственных интересах, а также создать организации недопустимые
> конкурентные преимущества. Кроме того, добавил суд, такое наименование
> может ввести в заблуждение потребителей услуг и принадлежности такой
> организации к федеральным органам исполнительной власти, органам
> государственной власти субъектов и органам местного самоуправления.**

Возможно зарегистрировать АО «Сочи Парк» без дефиса сложно, потому что использование названия города Сочи в названии организации может создавать у граждан ложное впечатление, что эта организация государственная или как-то связна с государственной действенностью. Поэтому решили соединить «Сочи» и «Парк» дефисом создав как бы одно слово АО «Сочи-Парк». Но это касается только юридического названия, а обычное название Сочи Парк.

Comment: Любопытно было бы узнать, как этот парк называется в официальных документах. Скажем, акционерное общество, которое там заправляет, называется через дефис: ОАО "Сочи-Парк" (официальные реквизиты легко гуглятся).

Comment: @grizzly В [правила посещения парка](https://www.sochipark.ru/about/visit-rules/) название организации АО «Сочи-Парк», но написано: «Правила посещения Тематического парка „Сочи Парк“». Я думаю, что название организации может отличаться от названия самого парка.

Comment: @grizzly Насчёт слова «Парк» с большой буквы, я думаю тут имеет место подражание английскому правописанию, в котором все слова в названиях пишутся с большой буквы, например, ["Hyde Park"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyde_Park,_London).

Comment: @grizzly Я там дополнил в конце по поводу отличия Сочи Парк и ОАО «Сочи-Парк».

Comment: Пример с Гайд-парком особенно хорош, потому что его написание зафиксировано в авторитетных словарях и объяснено [в правилах](https://orfogrammka.ru/орфография/географические_и_административно_территориальные_названия/) (см. Примечание 3 в конце). По поводу заглавной буквы в слове "Парк" Вас также может заинтересовать хороший пример в [Вопросе № 274454 на Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=274454).

Answer (score 2):

Дефисное написание используется **в официальных документах**, но парк более известен под названием **Сочи Парк**.

[https://nicko.ru/сочи-парк-путеводитель-от-а-до-я/](https://nicko.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%8F/)

Но при этом надо остановиться на одном варианте и привести орфографию в определенную систему.

Тогда мы берем (например, в путеводителях)  существующее название **Сочи Парк**  за основу и рассматриваем его как некое **устойчивое сочетание**, которое может **изменяться по падежам**: Сочи Парк, Сочи Парка и т.д..

Но при этом нужно придерживаться одной формы, то есть **не использовать** другие варианты письма – *Сочи-парк, Сочи парк, Сочи-Парк*, как это иногда делается. Тогда подобные записи следует считать некорректными.

**Как объяснить правильность двух различных названий**

Нам приходится использовать варианты названий в разных стилях речи (официальном и общеупотребительном) в соответствии **с существующей традицией.**

Имена собственные состоят обычно из **условной части** (написание с прописной буквы) и **родовых наименований** (парк, написание со строчной буквы).

В данном случае в условную часть имени собственного (написание с прописной буквы) будут входить **оба слова** (Сочи Парк), причем первое слово не будет склоняться.

Тогда мы будем находиться **в правовом поле**, даже используя такое нестандартное название.

**Примечание.** И это совсем не то, что ресторан "На Берегу Москва Река". Правильная запись такого названия: ресторан "На берегу Москвы-реки", здесь нет необходимости в использовании нестандартных вариантов.

Comment: Замечу, что по Вашей ссылке встречается и дефисное написание: *"Сочи-Парк выдержан частично в стилистике русских сказок, былин и мифов, частично в стилистике науки. Так аттракционы здесь называются «Жар Птица»..."*. Вот это "Жар Птица" пишется по тому же правилу, что и "Сочи Парк". Вполне в духе такого правила название ресторана "На Берегу Москва Река". Не по душе мне это правило :(